# Light slider data-thumb image path is not binding from database using Eval()

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, repeater

I'm using jQuery Light Slider with repeater control to show the image from database as like:

```
<ul id="imageGallery">
    <asp:Repeater ID="rpImage" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li data-thumb='<%# "~/Images/"+Eval("imgImagePath") %>'>
                <asp:Image ID="img" CssClass="image-width"
                    ImageUrl='<%# "~/Images/"+Eval("imgImagePath") %>' runat="server" />
            </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</ul>
```

In repeater, asp Image is binding successfully but Light Slider's `data-thumb` is not binding as:

```
data-thumb='<%# "~/Images/"+Eval("imgImagePath") %>'
```

How I can fix above problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply use

```html
<li data-thumb='<%# "/Images/"+Eval("imgImagePath") %>'>
insteed of 
<li data-thumb='<%# "~/Images/"+Eval("imgImagePath") %>'>
```

Please omit ~ in path

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)